# Disappearing lines and misplaced rotated arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, pgf-decorations

The issue is illustrated in the below MWE (and the full preamble we have used is in the comment at the end). When the curly brace decorations have been added, the original lines disappeared and their arrowheads moved to the right end of the curly braces and rotated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

Original diagram that I am trying to add the curly braces to:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);

\draw[-triangle 45] (0,0) -- ($(a)+(b)$) node[right,below,xshift=-1.5cm] {$\vv{a+b}$};
\draw[-triangle 45,blue] (0,0) -- (a) node[midway,below,xshift=1.5cm] {$\vv{a}$};
\draw[-triangle 45,red] (0,0) -- (b) node[midway,below] {$\vv{b}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

This looks a bit confusing as the labels look as they apply to the wrong sections of the vectors and their sum.

This demonstrates the issue with the arrow heads after adding the curly braces and staggering the labels along Y axis:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);

\draw[-triangle 45,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1.5cm},decorate] (0,0) -- ($(a)+(b)$) node[midway,below=1.5cm] {$\vv{a+b}$};
\draw[-triangle 45,blue,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1cm},decorate] (0,0) -- (a) node[midway,below=1cm] {$\vv{a}$};
\draw[-triangle 45,red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=0.5cm},decorate] (0,0) -- (b) node[midway,below=0.5cm] {$\vv{b}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

The vector lines are gone and the arrow heads are at what looks like 30-45 degree angle.

\end{document}

% The original document's full preamble:

%\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xstring}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{esvect}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{braket}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\everymath{\displaystyle}
%
%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepgflibrary{intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,angles,quotes}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

[image]

Was able to solve the presentation issue for the time being by staggering the vectors themselves w/o adding the braces, but still would like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Use `postaction={decorate,draw,-}` as an additional key for the `\draw` commands like `\draw[-triangle 45,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1.5cm},postaction={decorate,draw,-}]`

Comment: @esdd Do I need to load a library for that?

Comment: You need the `decorations.pathreplacing` library. But `pgfplots` loads `tikz` and this library.

Comment: @esdd Not sure what I am doing wrong, w/o that library it does not compile, and with that library it does not too, but with a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate the path as a `postaction`:

```
\draw
  [-triangle 45]
  [postaction={decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1.5cm},decorate,draw,-}]
  (0,0) -- ($(a)+(b)$) node[midway,below=1.5cm] {$\vv{a+b}$};
```

But I would use a `scope`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,
    decorations.pathreplacing% for the brace decoration
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);

\begin{scope}[
    -triangle 45,
    mybrace/.style={postaction={decoration={brace,mirror,raise=#1},decorate,draw,-}}
  ]
  \draw[mybrace=1.5cm] (0,0) -- ($(a)+(b)$) node[midway,below=1.5cm] {$\vv{a+b}$};
  \draw[blue,mybrace=1cm] (0,0) -- (a) node[midway,below=1cm] {$\vv{a}$};
  \draw[red,mybrace=.5cm] (0,0) -- (b) node[midway,below=0.5cm] {$\vv{b}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Got it! `decoration` converts a line into the specified decoration, but `postprocessing` adds a specified decoration to an already drawn line.